# publishConfig is not respected by Yarn 1.22

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I'm using yarn `v1.22` and yarn workspace for building my application as a monorepo. Here is the `package.json` for our component library package. I want to use `publishConfig` to override the `main` field when I do `npm publish` or `yarn publish`. But when I tried to run those commands, the `main` field is no changed. Can anyone share some suggestions? Thanks.

```json
{
  "name": "components",
  "private": false,
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "main": "dist/index.js"
  }
}
```